# How to pass lookup value searched in flow to a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lookup

[image]I have a lightning flow.

In my flow I have used a lookup screen component for a lookup field. I am storing the Id in a flow variable.

Now I have a lightning component just below the lookup, to which I need to pass the  lookup Id from the above screen component. I am passing the above flow variable to an attribute in lightning component.

But my issue here is that, the Lookup Id should be passed in lightning component, after I have searched for a value in the screen lookup component. But this is not happening, the value passed to the lightning is always coming as null, even after I have searched for a record in lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values that change in a given screen won't affect the value of any other component on the page. The only thing that listens for changes in the screen at runtime is the conditional visibility -- otherwise, the changes are only registered when the Next button is clicked and everything is sent to the flow engine on the server.

If you want to set a value in the second Lightning component based on the value chosen in the first, you'll need to put the Lightning component in a subsequent screen.